# Law of Demeter - is it really communicating only to friends?

Tags: javascript, class, coding-style, law-of-demeter

I read some article on Law of Demeter and it gets me confused.

It states that something like this:

```
var width = mapControl.get_mapState().getMapRange().getSize().get_width();
```

Should be replaced by this:

```
var mapState = mapControl.get_mapState();
var mapRange = mapState.get_mapRange();
var width = mapRange.get_width()
```

I am a little confused here cause the latter one is just the same as the first one but written differently. In both cases I am eventually accessing "width" which is not a direct friend of my current class.

So why is the second way really better?

Comment: No, that article makes no sense. Would you mind linking it?

Comment: it was printed stuff, otherwise there would be some critical comments immediately below. That's why it got me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a little confiused here cause the latter one is just the same as the first one but written differently. In both cases I am eventually accessing "width" which is not a direct friend of my current class.
>
> So why is the second way really better?

It's not really better. A Law of Demeter approach would be to refactor the code, so the client code looks like this:

```
var width = mapControl.get_width();
```

In this case, client code doesn't need to know that mapControl has a "state", which has a "range", which has a "width". It just needs to know it exposes a "width".

Comment: That's how I understood it, I guess the source must have been not reliable and contained a misinterpretation.